# Using random function in selecting an object if two same distance values

Tags: java, collections, distance

I have an ArrayList `unsolvedOutlets` containing object `Outlet` that has attributes `longitude` and `latitude`.

Using the `longitude` and `latitude` of `Outlet` objects in ArrayList `unsolvedOutlets`, I need to find the smallest distance in that list using the distance formula : SQRT(((X2 - X1)^2)+(Y2-Y1)^2), wherein (X1, Y1) are given. I use `Collections.min(list)` in finding the smallest distance.

My problem is if there are two or more values with the same smallest distance, I'd have to randomly select one from them.

Code:

```
ArrayList<Double> distances = new ArrayList<Double>();
Double smallestDistance = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < unsolvedOutlets.size(); i++) {
    distances.add(Math.sqrt(
        (unsolvedOutlets.get(i).getLatitude() - currSolved.getLatitude())*
        (unsolvedOutlets.get(i).getLatitude() - currSolved.getLatitude())+
        (unsolvedOutlets.get(i).getLongitude() - currSolved.getLongitude())*
        (unsolvedOutlets.get(i).getLongitude() - currSolved.getLongitude())));
    distances.add(0.0); //added this to test 
    distances.add(0.0); //added this to test 
    smallestDistance = Collections.min(distances);   
    System.out.println(smallestDistance);                                     
}
```

The outcome in the console would print out `0.0` but it wont stop. Is there a way to know if there are multiple values with **same smallest value**. Then I'd incorporate the `Random` function. Did that make sense? lol but if anyone would have the logic for that, it would be really helpful!!

Thank you!

Comment: For one thing, it looks like you're picking the smallest distance *inside your loop*. I assume that was unintentional? Also note that if you're just trying to compare distances, you don't need to call `Math.sqrt` - you can just keep the square of the distance. (That won't affect ordering.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I used `Math.sqrt` because I needed to get the distance formula and I saved the calculated values in the `distances` ArrayList. But I get your point in finding the smallest distance in the loop; it was unintentional haha

Comment: Why do you think you need the actual distance? You only need to know which outlet is closest, right? That means you just need something which sorts in the same order as the distance - and the square of the distance gets you that, but with less work.

Comment: Find the min value, then loop over the list to find all the elements with a distance equal to the found min distance, and pick randomly into these values.

Comment: The correct formula for distances on the surface of a sphere is found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833002/distance-between-two-points-in-spherical-coordinates).  What  you're doing is really only accurate if you stay close to the equator.

Comment: Oops, that's actually the chord distance, not the great circle distance.  Of course, it doesn't matter, when all you're doing is finding the least one.  Anyway, the correct formula for the great circle distance is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep track of the indices with min distance in your loop and after the loop choose one at random:

```
Random random = ...
...
List<Integer> minDistanceIndices = new ArrayList<>();

double smallestDistance = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < unsolvedOutlets.size(); i++) {
    double newDistance = Math.sqrt(
        (unsolvedOutlets.get(i).getLatitude() - currSolved.getLatitude())*
        (unsolvedOutlets.get(i).getLatitude() - currSolved.getLatitude())+
        (unsolvedOutlets.get(i).getLongitude() - currSolved.getLongitude())*
        (unsolvedOutlets.get(i).getLongitude() - currSolved.getLongitude()));
    distances.add(newDistance);
    if (newDistance < smallestDistance) {
         minDistanceIndices.clear();
         minDistanceIndices.add(i);
         smallestDistance = newDistance;
    } else if (newDistance == smallestDistance) {
         minDistanceIndices.add(i);
    }                             
}

if (!unsolvedOutlets.isEmpty()) {
     int index = minDistanceIndices.get(random.nextInt(minDistanceIndices.size()));
     Object chosenOutlet = unsolvedOutlets.get(index);
     System.out.println("chosen outlet: "+ chosenOutlet);
}
```

As Jon Skeet mentioned you don't need to take the square root to compare the distances.

Also if you want to use distances on a sphere your formula is wrong:
With your formula you'll get the same distance for (0° N, 180° E) to (0° N, 0° E) as for (90° N, 180° E) to (90° N, 0° E), but while you need to travel around half the earth to travel from the first to the second, the last 2 coordinates both denote the north pole.

Comment: This is far more efficient than Jon Skeet's solution or JB Nizet's solution.  And well done for pointing out the problem with the distance formula.

Comment: Yes, I like this one more too :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think there's still value in your solution.  Two upvoters agreed with me.  It can be really good for a learner to be able to see more than one way of solving a problem of this kind.  I urge you to consider undeleting it.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I believe fabian's solution is superior to this, but I've kept it around to demonstrate that there are many different ways of implementing this...

I would probably:

- Create a new type which contained the distance from the outlet as well as the outlet (or just the square of the distance), or use a generic `Pair` type for the same purpose
- Map (using `Stream.map`) the original list to a list of these pairs
- Order by the distance or square-of-distance
- Look through the sorted list until you find a distance which isn't the same as the first one in the list

You then know how many - and which - outlets have the same distance.

Another option would be to simply shuffle the original collection, then sort the result by distance, then take the first element - that way even if multiple of them *do* have the same distance, you'll be taking a random one of those.

JB Nizet's option of "find the minimum, then perform a second scan to find all those with that distance" would be fine too - and quite possibly simpler :) Lots of options...

Comment: The mapping method avoids a second scan, while being just as simple if not simpler, so it's better IMO. +1 --- Personally, I'd simply have a method with a custom `Comparator` to order `unsolvedOutlets` for distance according to the given coordinates (parameters), which would return a `List` of all instances with the same (smallest) distance as the first; and then choose randomly from that list. If I understand correctly, that's pretty much the same as you're doing. --- PS: Jon, you always come up with the simple but complete answers, as always. =)